# using the root test to prove a series is convergent for $|x| < r$

Tags: real-analysis

let $s(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$. Let $s = \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$. Let $r$ be the radius of convergence $r = 1/s$.

Assume $r>0$ show that $s(x)$ converges for $|x| < r$ and does not for $|x|> r$

Let $|x|<r$

we have $(|a_n|x^n)^{1/n} = |a_n|^{1/n} |x| \leq \sup |a_n|^{1/n} |x| \to s|x| $ so if $|x| < r$ then we get $(|a_n|x^n)^{1/n} \to |x|s < rs = s/s = 1$

Then by the root test the series converges. I am uncomfortable with the step $"|a_n|^{1/n} |x| \leq \sup |a_n|^{1/n} |x|"$ because I'm not really sure what $s = \lim \sup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$ really means.

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $|x| < r$. If $x = 0$, $s(x) = 0$, so assume $0 < |x| < r$. Then $s < 1/|x|$, so there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n|^{1/n} < 1/|x|$ for all $n \ge N$. Consequently, $|a_n|r^n < r^n/|x|^n = (r/|x|)^n$ for all $n \ge N$. Since $0 < r/|x| < 1$, the geometric series $\sum_{n = 1}^n (r/|x|)^n$ converges. So by direct comparison $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n|r^n$ converges. Since $|a_n x^n| < |a_n|r^n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, again by direct comparison $s(x)$ converges absolutely.

Now suppose $|x| > r$. Then $s > 1/|x|$, so $|a_n|^{1/n} > 1/|x|$ for infinitely many $n$. So $|a_n|r^n > r^n/|x|^n = (r/|x|)^n$ for infinitely many $n$. As $r/|x| > 1$, the geometric series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (r/|x|)^n$ diverges, which implies $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n|r^n$ diverges. So since $|a_nx^n| > |a_n|r^n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, we deduce by comparison that $s(x)$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks. What is wrong with my root test approach?

Comment: The theorem you're trying to prove is the root test.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm trying to use the root test to prove it, I don't see how you've proven the root test with your proof. This seems like a direct application of the root test, and it should just "fall out"

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding. I'm talking about the statement of the problem. You don't know that $\lim |a_n|^{1/n}$ exists, so you're argument is invalid. I used the definition of limsup and the comparison test for series to prove the theorem.

Comment: By the way, $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n} = \inf_{n \ge 1} \sup_{k\ge n} |a_k|^{1/k}$.

Comment: If we know $s$ exists, why do we need to know if $\lim |a_n|^{1/n}$ exists?

Comment: You don't need to know $\lim |a_n|^{1/n}$ exists. What I'm saying is your argument is dependent on knowing $\lim |a_n|^{1/n}$ exists. Also, it's not necessarily true that $\sup_{n \ge 1} |a_n|^{1/n} \to s$.